# Run a Go routine indefinitely (restart when done)

Tags: go

I am rewriting my TypeScript projects to Golang and I encountered a problem:

I am running a for loop which starts up async workers on program load. If I understood correctly Go routines are a way to run async code concurrently. What I'd like to do is restart the function once it is done, indefinitely.

In TypeScript it looks something like

```
async function init() {
  const count = async Users.getCount();

  // run all workers concurrently
  for (let i = 0; i < count; i += PER_WORKER) {
    const id = i / PER_WORKER;
    worker(id);
  }
}

async worker(id: number) {
  await new Promise((resolve) => {
    // do stuff
    resolve();
  })

  // restart function
  worker(workerId);
}
```

in Go I have pretty similar stuff, but when re-calling the function inside it just makes a mess? I thought of running the function by interval but I cannot know in advance the time it takes...

Thank you
NVH

Comment: `What I'd like to do is restart the function once it is done, indefinitely.` Can't you just run it in a loop?

Comment: Since the first loop is running all workers concurrently I have no way of knowing when one of them is done and restart it do I ?

Comment: Why do the workers `finish` work though? They should probably just keep working, like a thread-pool with a work-queue.

Comment: What they do is iterate over a portion of a database (with limit and offset), since it challenges the data with an API it is faster to do them concurrently, at one point or an another I have to know when it's done and rerun it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> What I'd like to do is restart the function once it is done, indefinitely.

You need a forever loop, of course:

```
for {
    f()
}
```

If you want to spin off the forever loop itself, put that in a function and invoke it with `go`:

```
go func() {
    for {
        f()
    }
}()
```

That is, we spin off the `for` loop itself; the `for` loop calls our function once each time.  Doing this:

```
for {
    go f()
}
```

is wrong because that spins off `f()` an infinite number of times, as fast as it can, without waiting for `f()` to return.

Comment: I understand now tkausl's comment! That is clever. Thank you so much